How can I add a click event to a 3D entity in FXGL?
Box box = new Box(PlotConstant.WIDTH_X, PlotConstant.DEEP_Y, PlotConstant.LENGTH_Z);
        box.setMaterial(material);
        box.setDrawMode(DrawMode.FILL);
        Entity entity = entityBuilder(data)
                .at(data.getX(), data.getY(), data.getZ())
                .viewWithBBox(box)
                .with(new IDComponent(data.get("name"), data.get("id")))
                .onClick(e->{
                    System.out.println("click box");
                })
                .build();

Clicking on this box does not trigger the mouse click event.
I have tried using entity.getViewComponent().addOnClickHandler and entityBuilder().onClick, but it seems that these methods do not work.

I don't use fxgl , but if  box inherits Shape3D  you can  use box.setOnMouseClicked()

See picking - that is about JavaFX nodes, for FXGL, I don’t know how it translates.
